# Connect mongodb to a database with doctrine 2 on codeigniter 3

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-3, doctrine-odm

We are currently in workplacement to finish our formation. The objective of our project is to improve the current web application of our company, develop with the framework Codeigniter.
The app uses a mysql database with PhpMyAdmin. We have to use an other database with mongoDB and DoctrineODM.
We start by the install of Composer from  getcomposer. We use Composer to integrate Doctrine into CodeIgniter using the explanation of this link : http://blog.beheist.com/integrating-codeigniter-and-doctrine-2-orm-with-composer/
After that, we integrate the library mongoDB with the SETUP explain here : 
doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/introduction.html
After trying to create a connection to the database, our work placement mentor delete the bootstrap.php file previously created. We also replace the doctrine.php file by DoctrineODM.php from here :  github.com/openstepmedia/cibongo/blob/dev/bonfire/libraries/DoctrineODM.php 
We have change a bit the code because we are not using Bonfire.

DoctrineODM.php

```
//phpinfo(); exit();


use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader,
    Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Configuration,
    Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader,
    Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver,
    Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager,
    Doctrine\MongoDB\Connection;
/**
 * Doctrine bootstrap library for CodeIgniter
 *
 * @author  Joseph Wynn <joseph@wildlyinaccurate.com>
 * @link    http://wildlyinaccurate.com/integrating-doctrine-2-with-codeigniter-2
 */
class DoctrineODM
   {
   public $em;    
   public $dm;
   public function __construct()
{
        require APPPATH.'config/doctrine.php';

        // With this configuration, your model files need to be in application/models/Entity
        // e.g. Creating a new Entity\User loads the class from application/models/Entity/User.php
        //$models_namespace = 'Documents';
    // Set up driver
        foreach (glob(APPPATH . 'modules/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $m) {
            $module = str_replace(APPPATH . 'modules/', '', $m);
            $loader = new ClassLoader($module, APPPATH . 'modules');
            $loader->register();
        }



        $models = array(APPPATH . 'models');
        $loader = new ClassLoader('models/', $models);
        $loader->register();

        foreach (glob(APPPATH . 'modules/*/models', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $m) {
            array_push($models, $m);
        }
        //$models_path = APPPATH . 'models';
        $proxies_dir = APPPATH . 'models/Proxies';
        $hydrators_dir = APPPATH . 'models/Hydrators';
        $metadata_paths = array(APPPATH . 'models');
        $config = new Configuration();
        $config->setDefaultDB($db['default']['database']);
        $config->setProxyDir($proxies_dir);
        $config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');
        $config->setHydratorDir($hydrators_dir);
        $config->setHydratorNamespace('Hydrators');
        //$annotationDriver = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(array($models_path . '/Documents'));
        $annotationDriver = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver($models);
        $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($annotationDriver);
        AnnotationDriver::registerAnnotationClasses();
        try {
        $connection = new Connection($db['default']['server'] );
            $this->dm = DocumentManager::create($connection, $config);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
        //$this->generate_classes();
}
```

Maybe that was not the good choice, but after that the connection (MongoClient) still on NULL .
We created then the class models/Entity/User.php by ourselves to check if Doctrine was working .
We get this error :

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/www/fast-mage/admin/applicationhiddenci/librariesKint/Kint.php:276)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 573

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException
Message: Class 'User' does not exist
Filename: /home/www/fast-mage/admin/applicationhiddenci/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php
Line Number: 96
```

We are now block, and we don't know where to look for, the data (server,hostname,id,…) of the database are on the DocumentManager but MongoClient stay on NULL.
Thank you for reading,sorry for my bad english and thank you for your possible help.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear:

```
Class 'User' does not exist
```

Have you created your `User` entity?

Comment: I think so, I create the entity User.php in the folder Entities with this : 
   
    <?php
    use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;
    namespace Documents;
    /** @ODM\Document */
    class User
    {
        /** @ODM\Id */
        private $id;
    
        /** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
        private $name;

        /** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
        private $email;

        /** @ODM\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="BlogPost", cascade="all") */
        private $posts = array();

         // ...
     } 
    ?>

Comment: You have declared this class to be in the namespace `Documents`. So I'm guessing that when you ask Doctrine to use the class `User`, Doctrine will actually look for a class `User` in the globale namespace (`\User`), whilst it should look in the `Documents` namespace (`\Documents\User`).

I don't know what kind of autoloading you have setup, but I think it is good practise to match the directory structure (i.e. follow PSR0/4).